# Lifetime of item per std of day activity

Tags: statistical-significance, standard-deviation

I'd like to get advise if I'm doing it right.

I have following dataframe (below attached) with the activities count with occurred date. An also per "Slug" I have its published day, e.g. zero-day in different dataframe. So I need to figure out what the probable lifetime (in days) of any random "Slug" is?

So I computed in separate column "lifetime" the difference between **occurred_date - zero_day**, then I plotted it in `seaborn.distplot`.

**Question**: Is it fair to say according to this PDF that any random "Slug" will live 0-50 days with 1-2% probability? (too few probability though). What would you advise to do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Normally I'd say this is duration modeling (or, depending on your discipline, survival analysis), but since there are multiple occurrences of each item, that does not appear to be the straightforward case. What is `lifetime` in this context? When does it 'end' (failure condition)?

Comment: in my case I have popularity per activity `Count`. Think of `lifetime` as this: you have audio/video which is being viewed/searched (some activity) and you track it keeping activity date. You also have `t0` date when your product was published. So you need to get the probable duration of your product's popularity

and thanks for Survival Analysis.

Comment: That's an arrival process then. When we assume a distribution for those, a  Poisson process seems most intuitive. If we don't, a KDE should work too.